# matchAllQuery() in ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

matchAllQuery() in Elasticsearch gets me only 10 results how do I increase its output so that I can get as many results as per my requirement.

**Code**

```
 QueryBuilder query = QueryBuilders.matchAllQuery();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes u can do , here you can pass `aPageRequestcount` whatever you want  and If you want no of records exist in Elastic search than `repository.count()` will work for that :-

```
int aPageRequestcount = (int) repository.count();

NativeSearchQueryBuilder aNativeSearchQueryBuilder = new NativeSearchQueryBuilder();  
      aNativeSearchQueryBuilder.withIndices(indexName).withTypes(type).withPageable(new PageRequest(0, aPageRequestcount));
final BoolQueryBuilder aQuery = new BoolQueryBuilder();


NativeSearchQuery nativeSearchQuery = aNativeSearchQueryBuilder.withQuery(aQuery).build();
                = elasticsearchTemplate.queryForList(nativeSearchQuery, A.class);
```

Answer (score 3):

By default 10 results are returned, you need to increase the `size` parameter:

```
SearchRequestBuilder request = client.prepareSearch(index)
    .setQuery(QueryBuilders.matchAllQuery())
    .setSize(100);
```