# How to use matchQuery in java api elasticsearch client

Tags: java, spring, curl, elasticsearch

I m tring to use the matchQuery of java api elasticsearch but the curl return 0 documents.

Here my code:
**webservice:**

```
@RequestMapping(path = "/blog/search/{text}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public List<PostDocument> search(
    @PathVariable String text, 
    @RequestParam("from") int from, 
    @RequestParam("size") int size
) {
    return this.searchService.search(text, from, size);
}
```

**searchService.search:**

```
public List<PostDocument> search(String fulltextQuery, int from, int size) {
    SearchRequestBuilder searchRequestBuilder = this.client.prepareSearch(indexConfig.getIndexAlias());
    System.out.println(fulltextQuery);
    searchRequestBuilder.setQuery(this.createQuery(fulltextQuery));
    searchRequestBuilder.setFrom(from);
    searchRequestBuilder.setSize(size);

    SearchResponse response = searchRequestBuilder.get();

    return this.parseResponse(response);
}

private QueryBuilder createQuery(String fulltextQuery) {
    return QueryBuilders.matchQuery("title",fulltextQuery);
}
```

**my curl**
using postman

```
localhost:8080/blog/search/post?from=1&size=10
```

*result:*

```
[]
```

Someone help me please, i have an error in my code or in my curl.

I am sure that i have data in my elasticsearch

```
curl -XGET "localhost:9200/blog/_search?pretty" -d '{"query" : {"match" : {"title" : "blog"}}}'
{
  "took" : 1,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "successful" : 1,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "max_score" : 0.25811607,
    "hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "blog",
        "_type" : "post",
        "_id" : "1",
        "_score" : 0.25811607,
        "_source" : {
          "title" : "Blog post",
          "content" : "My super blog post"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I printed the response, it return that he find a 2 docs but the list of hits is empty

```
{"took":1,"timed_out":false,"_shards":{"total":1,"successful":1,"failed":0},"hits":{"total":2,"max_score":0.96669346,"hits":[]}}
```

Here the console log after setting from = 0

```
2017-04-26 09:23:48.756 ERROR 26327 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException] with root cause

java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at fr.oss.es.devbasics.search.blog.controller.SearchService.parseResponse2(SearchService.java:115) ~[classes/:na]
    at fr.oss.es.devbasics.search.blog.controller.SearchService.searchtest(SearchService.java:43) ~[classes/:na]
    at fr.oss.es.devbasics.search.blog.controller.SearchController.search(SearchController.java:30) ~[classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205) ~[spring-web-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:133) ~[spring-web-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:116) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:963) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:230) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) ~[spring-web-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:105) ~[spring-web-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:81) ~[spring-web-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197) ~[spring-web-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:474) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:349) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:783) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:798) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1434) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_111]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_111]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_111]
```

Here my code: **parseResponse2**

```
private List<PostDocument> parseResponse2(SearchResponse response) {
        List<PostDocument> docs = new ArrayList<PostDocument>();

        SearchHit[] hits = response.getHits().getHits();

        for(SearchHit hit: hits) {
           Post post = new Post(hit.sourceAsMap().get("title").toString(), hit.sourceAsMap().get("content").toString());
           post.setId(Long.parseLong(hit.sourceAsMap().get("id").toString()));
           docs.add(new PostDocument(hit.index(), post));
        }

        return docs;
    }
```

Regards

Comment: Can you print out the query that's being generated by your code as well?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43601775/matchallquery-in-elasticsearch probably this might help you :) and I guess answer from @Val will help you even further :)

Comment: Here the query:
{
  "multi_match" : {
    "query" : "post",
    "fields" : [
      "content^1.0",
      "title^1.0"
    ],
    "type" : "best_fields",
    "operator" : "OR",
    "slop" : 0,
    "prefix_length" : 0,
    "max_expansions" : 50,
    "lenient" : false,
    "zero_terms_query" : "NONE",
    "boost" : 1.0
  }
}

Comment: How come your query contains a `multi_match` while your Java code uses `match`? Are you sure this is the query being generated?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you have one document, and `from` should start from 0 but you input 1 instead.

Try this URL and it should work:

```
localhost:8080/blog/search/post?from=0&size=10
                                     ^
                                     |
                                change this
```

Comment: I get this error
{
  "timestamp": 1493191428761,
  "status": 500,
  "error": "Internal Server Error",
  "exception": "java.lang.NullPointerException",
  "message": "No message available",
  "path": "/blog/search/post"
}

Comment: Can you also share your ES server logs around that time?

Comment: Ok, then the issue is in your code. Do you have more info about that `NullPointerException` from your application log?

Comment: According to your stack trace, `parseResponse2()` is throwing that null pointer exception. Do you mind to show the code? (update your question please)

Comment: private List<PostDocument> parseResponse2(SearchResponse response) {
        List<PostDocument> docs = new ArrayList<PostDocument>();
        
        SearchHit[] hits = response.getHits().getHits();
        
        for(SearchHit hit: hits) {
           Post post = new Post(hit.sourceAsMap().get("title").toString(), hit.sourceAsMap().get("content").toString());
           post.setId(Long.parseLong(hit.sourceAsMap().get("id").toString()));
           docs.add(new PostDocument(hit.index(), post));
        }
        
        return docs;
    }

Comment: it s normal i got nullpointerexception because the list hits is empty, the problem that the request dont return value in hits.
"hits":{"total":2,"max_score":0.96669346,"hits":[]

Comment: A null pointer exception is **never normal**, you need to protect your code against that. As requested earlier, can you share the exact query that is generated by your code and share it?

Comment: { "multi_match" : { "query" : "post", "fields" : [ "content^1.0", "title^1.0" ], "type" : "best_fields", "operator" : "OR", "slop" : 0, "prefix_length" : 0, "max_expansions" : 50, "lenient" : false, "zero_terms_query" : "NONE", "boost" : 1.0 } }

Comment: The full request that gets sent out, not only the query part. Moreover I don't understand how this query can be generated from `matchQuery("title")`. Are you sure your code above is in synch with what you're running now?

Comment: I just change matchquery by multiMatchQuery

Answer (score 0):

try with localhost:8080/blog/post/_search/?from=1&size=10

Try with `hardcoding index name and type name`

JAVA API code :-

```
QueryBuilder searchQuery = QueryBuilders.matchQuery("title", "");

SearchRequestBuilder countRequestBuilder = esClient.prepareSearch("INDEXNAME").setTypes("TYPE").setQuery(searchQuery);
SearchResponse response = countRequestBuilder.execute().actionGet("ACTION_TIMEOUT"), TimeUnit.SECONDS);

SearchHit[] seacrhHits = response.getHits().getHits();
```